# Object won't move when I add Soft-Body physics

Tags: physics, soft-body

I got the object with the soft-body to work at first but now it refuses to move at all when I press play. The only way to get it to move again is to start a brand new project and redo everything.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I need to press Playback and then "Set Start Frame." Didn't have to do that before so I don't know why I have to do that now. Hope they change this later one.

Comment: What version are you using?